# SSIS cannot acquire connection from connection manager

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I moved a perfectly fine working package to another laptop and it fail to run run now. (I did this before to another laptop and everything worked fine then)

The package fails after running a foreach loop with a control flow. I want to load several Excel files into a database.

I'm getting this error message:

> [Read CP XL File [14]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed. [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Read CP
>   XL File failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Sidenote, there is no error message posted before.

I tried to:

- Run in 32 bit
- Creating a new connection
- Set `DelayValidation` on both True and False.
- Loading less files "at the same time".
- Changing the protection level.

Does anyone now a solution?

Comment: XLS vs XLSX? Are you using a different version of Excel on the new laptop?

Comment: @JacobH, changing the extension form xlsx to xls did the job. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @JacobH you should write this as an answer